# Regex getting data between brackets

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a file I am inputting and need to process.
It contains several parameters inside that need to be stored.
This does not need to be done via RegEx/Pattern, but I feel that this would be most efficient. I have looked at some Regex tutorials but none seem to tell me what I need.

Sample File (Just created for an example

```
Characters = {e, o, d, f},
Values = {true, true, false, true}
```

I will be placing everything in each {} into an array, which is simple once I get the string.

So, again, how would I just obtain e, o, d, f    and true, true, false, true

Comment: what is your questions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` method this way:

```
 String text = "Values = {true, true, false, true}";
 String[] values = text.split(",\\s|.*?\\s=\\s\\{|\\}.*");
```

This is using 3 patterns to split (comma, what's before curly brace uncluding the brace, and last curly brace including what's after it).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to regexes is to grab the entire string inside the brackets and then do a `String.split(",");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
String line = "Values = {true, true, false, true}";

// replacing anything before { and anything after } with 'empty'
line = line.replaceAll(".*?\\{|\\}.*", "");

// splitting the string with comma(with optional spaces around)
String []values = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");

for(String v : values){
    System.out.println(v);
}
```